# return value std::mismatch for equal vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I am using [`std::mismatch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch) to check whether two vectors of structs are exactly the same. Usually, in my program, they are not, but in exceptional cases it might happen. In the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/mismatch/) I find the following:

> "If the elements compared in both sequences have all matched, the function returns a pair with first set to last1 and second set to the element in that same relative position in the second sequence."

However, if I create two vectors that are completely equal, std::mismatch does not return a value. A small example of what I am trying to do:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

struct structwithnumber {
    int id;
};

bool compare_structs (structwithnumber* struct1, structwithnumber* struct2) {
    return struct1->id == struct2->id;
};

bool compare_structvectors(std::vector<structwithnumber*> v1, std::vector<structwithnumber*> v2) {
    if (v1.size() != v2.size())
    {
        return false;
    }
    std::pair<std::vector<structwithnumber*>::iterator, std::vector<structwithnumber*>::iterator> mypair;
    mypair = std::mismatch(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), compare_structs);
    return (compare_structs(*mypair.first, *mypair.second));
}

void simple_example() {
    structwithnumber* struct1 = new structwithnumber();
    structwithnumber* struct2 = new structwithnumber();
    struct1->id = 1;
    struct2->id = 2;
    std::vector<structwithnumber*> v1;
    std::vector<structwithnumber*> v2;
    v1.push_back(struct1);
    v1.push_back(struct2);
    v2.push_back(struct1);
    v2.push_back(struct2);
    compare_structvectors(v1, v2);
}
```

When I run this code in visual studios 15 I get an error on the line:

```
 return (compare_structs(*mypair.first, *mypair.second));
```

On further investigation it turns out mypair remains empty after mismatch. From the documentation, I though this would return the last value of each vector. Did I misunderstand how mismatch would behave when presented with 2 sequences in which all elements match?

Comment: "I get an error" – would you care sharing with your audience the nature of that error? (Copy and paste from the Output window.)

Comment: And [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch) is a more reliable reference site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::mismatch`, in case everything matches, returns a(t least one) past-the-end iterator. You cannot dereference it as you're doing in `compare_structs(*mypair.first, *mypair.second)`.

The code should test for the case as follows:

```
mypair = std::mismatch(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), compare_structs);

if(mypair.first == v1.end()) {
    // No mismatch, do something sensible
} else {
    return (compare_structs(*mypair.first, *mypair.second));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will change it to: 

    mypair = std::mismatch(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), compare_structs); 
    return (mypair.first == v1.end());

As the second statement will always be false.

Comment: always depending on "mypair.first == v1.end()" can be wrong since c++14. Documentation says "f no mismatches are found when the comparison reaches last1 or last2, whichever happens first, the pair holds the end iterator and the corresponding iterator from the other range"

Comment: @AnandShah that's for the overload with two end iterators, while there's only one in OP's code. I'm not sure why the note about UB has been removed, since that's the only possible outcome if the second range is shorter than the first.

Answer (score 0):

> However, if I create two vectors that are completely equal, std::mismatch does not return a value

Of course it does, it has to return *something*.

> On further investigation it turns out mypair remains empty after mismatch.

What does that mean? How is mypair *empty*? It's a pair, it had exactly two members when it was created, and it still has exactly two members after the call to `mismatch`.

However, when both sequences match, it's a pair of `end` iterators.
That's like saying you have a pair of empty mismatched sequences (which is still not the same as an impossible *empty pair*).

You can't dereference these iterators, so your code that does so is broken. You need to test before dereferencing:

```
const bool v1_mismatch = (mypair.first != v1.end());
const bool v2_mismatch = (mypair.second != v2.end());
const bool identical = !(v1_mismatch || v2_mismatch);

if (v1_mismatch && v2_mismatch) {
    // this is the only case where you can dereference both
    return compare_structs(*mypair.first, *mypair.second);
}
// otherwise you can dereference at most one iterator,
// and if v1,v2 are identical, you can't dereference either
```